# visual studio 16.11.5 git errors, "Failed to fetch from the remote repository"

Tags: visual-studio

I've just upgraded to Visual Studio 16.11.5. When I do I get errors trying to connect to Azure devops. Azure shows the connection as successful but Visual Studio gives you a helpful message saying

"Failed to fetch from the remote repository".

It tells you to look in the output window, then the output window tells you to look in the output window :-)

NB This is different from similar stack overflow posts because this is specific to this release of Visual Studio. Prior releases did not have this issue. We've been able to verify this locally on a machine which worked before the upgrade and didn't after

Comment: I still experience this in 17.9, found a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you clear your authentication Manager setting then it appears to work again. Instructions here

https://jessehouwing.net/configure-visual-studio-to-use-a-different-git-credential-manager-for-windows/

but in case that link ever dies, find your .gitconfig file and just set

```
[credential]
    helper =
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-authenticate your credentials

1. Close current project
2. open Visual Studio (the splash screen) and click "Clone a repository"
3. click github
4. click the warning alert to re-authenticate
5. restart your project and attempt a push